# I'm using a 2008 Mac Pro as a home media server, how to get Wake On Network Access to work?

Tags: snow-leopard, sleep-wake, nas, home-sharing, wake-on-lan

I'm trying to make use of an old Mac Pro with 10.6.8 I had lying around as a wireless home media server, backed up with Time Machine.  I'm just using a standard Huawei router provided to me by my ISP. I've set up file sharing and screen sharing, so that I can access the files on the Mac Pro with my Macbook Pro. But is there a way that I can save power by having my Mac Pro constantly asleep, but wake up automatically when I want to access it from the Macbook Pro? Then go back to sleep once I'm done?

I've ticked the Wake For Access Network on my Mac Pro and Macbook Pro. But that doesn't work. I did some research and saw that you need an Airport or Apple TV with Bonjour Sleep Proxy to get it to work. Is there any way to get it to work with what just the Mac Pro and Macbook Pro?